# Bot cannot recognize message was deleted after ~5 seconds after initial send (server message delete)

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

I have a small unwanted feature where my bot cannot recognize if a message was deleted after like 5 seconds after the initial send. Below is my code for logging the deleted messages

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message_delete(self, c):
    if(c.guild):
        if c.guild.name == "Server Name":
            if c.author.bot == True:
                print(f"{c.created_at} || Bot: {c.author} deleted --- {c.content} --- in #{c.channel}");
            else:
                print(f"{c.created_at} || User: {c.author} deleted --- {c.content} --- in #{c.channel}");
```

I am aware that in the documentation there is a value called "max messages" which is tied to "on_message_delete". I was not able to implement it without success. I am looking for server-wide logging for example if someone deletes a message from like 5 days ago. If this is an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_delete(self, c):
        if(c.guild):
            if c.guild.name == "Sniper's lounge":
                if c.author.bot == True:
                    print(f"Bot: {c.author} deleted --- {c.clean_content} --- in #{c.channel.name}");
                    pass;
                else:
                    print(f"User: {c.author} deleted --- {c.clean_content} --- in #{c.channel.name}");
                    pass;
            elif c.guild.name == "New GAR":
                if c.author.bot == True:
                    print(f"Bot: {c.author} deleted --- {c.clean_content} --- in #{c.channel.name}");
                    pass;
                else:
                    print(f"User: {c.author} deleted --- {c.clean_content} --- in #{c.channel.name}");
                    pass;
        else:
            pass;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following event might help out a bit, as it doesn't require the message to be in the cache:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_message_delete(self, payload):
    if payload.guild_id:
        guild = self.bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
        if guild.name == "Server Name":
            if message.author.bot: # more pythonic way of checking bools
                print(...
            else:
                print(...
```

---

**References:**

- [`on_raw_message_delete()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_raw_message_delete)
- [The event's payload obj](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.RawMessageDeleteEvent)
- [`Client.get_guild()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_guild)
- [`Client.get_channel()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel)
- [`TextChannel.fetch_message()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.fetch_message)

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply, I tried following what you suggested unfortunately I am using a self bot not a traditional bot and I am getting an error "Only bots can use this endpoint", I am linking the Imgur screenshot of my code in case I made a mistake thanks.
https://imgur.com/a/DX6wya5

Comment: @DanA Sorry, I won't be helping you with making a self-bot, as it's against Discord's TOS.